# How is casting the column name in a SQL query different from casting the value

Tags: mysql, sql, teradata

Say for example

`cast(PURCHASE_DATE as date) > '2020-01-01'`

vs.

`PURCHASE_DATE > cast('2020-01-01' as date format)`

I have a few questions about the above:

1. I tested these on my application and they both lead to the same result. Is there a scenario where one would fail?
2. How are these two expressions different in terms of resource usage?
3. Does casting a column cast every value it wants to compare, as opposed to having the right hand side of that inequality cast once to be compared with all the values in that column?

Comment: What's the datatype of PURCHASE_DATE? There's no CAST in the 2nd code

Comment: Hey sorry, thank you for catching that, I updated it. It's also a cast. PURCHASE_DATE is also date format but assume it's anything but 'YYYY-MM-DD' which is why it needs casting in my case.

Comment: FORMAT phrase only applies when converting to/from character string. If PURCHASE_DATE is a DATE data type, no need for CAST on that side. It is preferred to use ANSI date literal such as `date'2020-01-01'` (always yyyy-mm-dd) for comparison such as this. If you must supply the date as a character string then you should use CAST or TO_DATE (with appropriate FORMAT) to convert to internal DATE type.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PURCHASE_DATE as DATETIME type colum, you could use CAST(colum AS DATE) so you can obtain better usage of the type of the colum and maybe in terms of scalability. The other way you just hardcoded the date variable and not use the benefits of the data type like change time zones if you ever use that. refer to: [11.2.2 The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, you don't need to cast a date is you use it this way:

```
WHERE PURCHASE_DATE > '2020-01-01'
```

or this, for numerics:

```
WHERE PURCHASE_ID > '0001000'
```

Teradata allows a lot of implicit casting.

Comment: The 1st might fail. It's a string and will be casted to a date using the format of the target column. If the format changes the cast will fall. The only safe way to write a date is a Standard SQL *date literal*: `DATE '2020-01-01'`